# problema python diccionarios

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo un problema para realizar este ejercicio:

Sea el diccionario `stock` una estructura que nos permitirá representar el stock que tenemos de una determinada pieza (la clave será el código de la pieza y el valor la cantidad disponible).

Un ejemplo sería:

```
stock={"A":5, "B":7, "Z":2, "X":1}
```

De la pieza "A" hay 5 unidades, de la "B" hay 7, etc...

Cuando se solicitan piezas, estas se indican en una lista de la siguiente manera:

```
solicitud=["A", "X", "A", "X", "B", "C"]
```

Esto significa que se solicitó una pieza "A", luego una "X", luego una "B" y finalmente una "C".

Se pide realizar una función `detectar_faltantes` que reciba como parámetro el diccionario del `stock` y una lista de piezas solicitadas; la función deberá retornar una lista donde se indiquen solamente qué piezas son las faltantes.

Por ejemplo, para el caso anterior, `detectar_faltantes(stock, solicitud)` debería retornar la lista `["X", "C"]` (porque se solicitaron dos piezas "X" cuando en el stock solo había una y una pieza "C" que como no está en el stock entonces es una pieza faltante).

Hasta ahora lo que llevo es esto:

```
def detectarfaltantes(stock,solicitud):
    faltantes=[]
    for pieza in stock:
        faltantes.append(stock[pieza])
        print(pieza)
     
print(detectarfaltantes({"A":5, "B":7, "Z":2, "X":1},["A", "X", "A", "X", "B", "C"] ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Por diseño, `stock` debe siempre tener una entrada por cada item válido, incluso si la existencia en cero. Eso simplifica el código y permite validar los ingresos (si el item no está en el diccionario, entonces no es un item válido). Por tanto, manejo `stock` con una entrada par "C" en cero:

```
stock={"A":5, "B":7, "Z":2, "X":1, "C":0}
```

Para revisar los faltantes, tengo que ir solicitud por solicitud, viendo si tienen existencia y, ojo!, rebajandola en una unidad.

Si no tiene existencia, la agrego a la lista `faltantes`.

Finalmente, devuelve la lista con `faltantes`.

```
def detectar_faltantes(stock, solicitud):
    faltantes = []
    for sol in solicitud:
        if stock[sol]:
            stock[sol] -= 1
        else:
            faltantes.append(sol)
    return faltantes
```

#### Demo

```
def detectar_faltantes(stock, solicitud):
    faltantes = []
    for sol in solicitud:
        if stock[sol]:
            stock[sol] -= 1
        else:
            faltantes.append(sol)
    return faltantes

stock={"A":5, "B":7, "Z":2, "X":1, "C":0}
solicitud=["A", "X", "A", "X", "B", "C"]

print(detectar_faltantes(stock, solicitud))
```

produce:

```
['X', 'C']

Process finished with exit code 0
```